# Sticky logo stop in halfway when scrolling

Tags: javascript, css

I have a logo in sticky position. I wanted the logo to stop in halfway on the top of home page when scrolling  and acting like a fixed until the the edge of footer.

```css
 body {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  margin:45px auto -50px; 
  background-color: yellow;
}

header {
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: #fff;
}

main {
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
   
<nav>
  <div class"logo">logo</div>
</nav>
<header>
</header>
<main>
<p>body text</p>
</main>
```

is that possible?

Comment: Yes this is possible with JS.

Comment: can you you teach me how?

Comment: There is no footer in your code...

Comment: hi @Terry my code here is just a sample

Answer (score 0):

```css
 body {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  margin:45px auto; 
  background-color: yellow;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -150px;
}

header {
  height: 40vh;
  background-color: #fff;
}

main {
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
   
<nav>
  <div class"logo">logo</div>
</nav>
<header>
</header>
<main>
<p>body text</p>
</main>
```

Comment: Hi @Amine thank you for your codes. however this is not what I meant. I wanted my logo will stop  halfway from the top of the webpage when scroll.